# dismissing UIKeyboard not working in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I have a view where there are two uitextfields. If a user taps on uitextfield1 , keyboard comes up and he can enter characters. when selected DONE , the keyboard resigns successfully. If user taps on uitextfield 2, i am dismissing the keyboard and show a datepicker in a subview where the user selects a date. Once the date is selected , the picker is dismissed and the selected date shows up in the uitextfield2 .

Here is the issue i am facing.

1) if we select textfield 1 and immediately select textfield 2 , the keyboard fails to go away . But when we select textfield 1 again and click DONE , the keyboard goes away .

I tried dismissing this , in uitextfield did begin editing ,uitextfield did end editing , uitextfield should return method . But in this case nothing works and the keyboard stays on the screen if we navigate to other pages.

Please help me to sort this problem .

Answer (score 0):

Use `[self.view endEditing:YES];` instead of `[uiTextField resignFirstResponder];`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you added `[textfield1 resignFirstResponder]` in the right places include `viewWillDisappear`,so it will be good if you can show some code snippet.